# Visual Studio returns error from Azure that a parameter isn't provided ... but it is

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I'm getting an error that a parameter, @BuyerCode, isn't being supplied.  It has a default value of 'None' and is set up as a C# Optional Parameter.

I'm attaching Visual Studio debugger to Azure, sorry.  I'm using Cloud Explorer.  Right clicking the web app, attaching debugger.

That's real bad on my part, not to say WHICH line the code fails on:
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() -- this line is now emphasized in the code.  Thanks for your patience.

The error is "The stored procedure ISSI_SEARCH_ADDSEARCHRESULT expects the parameter @BuyerCode which was not provided", something like that.

On my end it was a bit frustrating to not have ANYTHING work.  It was so disappointing I just wasn't communicating clearly.

I put in the rest of the SQL, sorry, I can't get it to format right. Andre did that for the first part.  I do use the {} symbol in the editor.

Here is the code snippet that calls the code in question.  I passed hard coded values, shown in parentheses.

```
     private void addSearchResult(
        string commandText
        , int SearchId
        , int SearchProviderId
        , string OEMPartNumber //customer part number
        , string ManufacturerPartNumber
        , string CustomerPartDescription
        , string VendorName
        , string City
        , string State
        , decimal Quantity
        , decimal SalePrice
        , string AvailableStock = "None"
        , decimal Cost = 0
        , decimal ExpediteFee = 0
        , **string BuyerCode = "None"** // there is a default provided
        , string VendorPartName = "None"
        , string CustomerPartName = "None"
        , decimal LocationId = 0
        , decimal VendorId = 0
        , int PartId = 0
        )
    {
```

Here is the last part of the method call now, with hard coded values passed:

```
                       , 0 //srList.Cost
                        , 0 //srList.ExpediteFee
                        , "None" //srList.BuyerCode
                        , "None" //srList.VendorPartName
                        , "None" //srList.CustomerPartName
                        , 0 //srList.LocationId
                        , 0 //srList.VendorId
                        , 0 //srList.PartId
```

Here is the code in the addSearchResult Method.  The only thing I can find in other posts is omitting this line of code, which I do have, ignore the asterisks that emphasize it:

```
 SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection();
 cnx.ConnectionString = ConxString;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchId", SearchId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SearchProviderId", SearchProviderId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerPartNumber", OEMPartNumber);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ManufacturerPartNumber", ManufacturerPartNumber);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerPartDescription", CustomerPartDescription);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VendorName", VendorName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", City);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("State", State);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", Quantity);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SalePrice", SalePrice);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AvailableStock", AvailableStock);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cost", Cost);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ExpediteFee", ExpediteFee);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BuyerCode", BuyerCode);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VendorPartName", VendorPartName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerPartName", CustomerPartName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LocationId", LocationId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VendorId", VendorId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartId", PartId);
 cmd.Connection = cnx;
 **cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;** <-- yep, this one's already here ... :) 
 cmd.CommandText = commandText;
 cnx.Open();
 *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();* //failure point is right here -- this line throws the error.
 cnx.Close();
```

The parameters in SQL are set up with NULL as defaults, parameter order in Values for the SQL does match the input, by the way:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ISSI_SEARCH_ADDSEARCHRESULT]
(
    @SearchId INT,
    @SearchProviderId INT,
    @CustomerPartNumber VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    @ManufacturerPartNumber VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    @CustomerPartDescription VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    @VendorName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    @City VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    @State VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    @Quantity NUMERIC(18,0) NULL,
    @SalePrice NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    @AvailableStock VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    @Cost NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    @ExpediteFee NUMERIC(10,2) NULL,
    @BuyerCode VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    @VendorPartName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    @CustomerPartName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    @LocationId INT NULL,
    @VendorId INT NULL,
    @PartId INT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
```

INSERT
    INTO [dbo].[visSearchResults]
    (
        SearchId ,
        SearchProviderId ,
        CustomerPartNumber  ,
        ManufacturerPartNumber  ,
        CustomerPartDescription  ,
        VendorName  ,
        City  ,
        State  ,
        Quantity , 
        SalePrice , 
        AvailableStock  ,
        Cost , 
        ExpediteFee , 
        BuyerCode  ,
        VendorPartName  ,
        CustomerPartName  ,
        LocationId  ,
        VendorId  ,
        PartId  ,
        Created
    )
    VALUES
    (
         @SearchId ,
        @SearchProviderId ,
        @CustomerPartNumber  ,
        @ManufacturerPartNumber  ,
        @CustomerPartDescription  ,
        @VendorName  ,
        @City  ,
        @State  ,
        @Quantity , 
        @SalePrice , 
        @AvailableStock  ,
        @Cost , 
        @ExpediteFee , 
        @BuyerCode  ,
        @VendorPartName  ,
        @CustomerPartName  ,
        @LocationId  ,
        @VendorId  ,
        @PartId  ,
        GETDATE()
    )

So I've tried it all.  The query runs at the database level.  I've checked the casing of BuyerCode, it's right.  Looked for leading or trailing whitespace, that's all good.

At my wits end here.

Comment: What is the value of BuyerCode when you set a breakpoint at "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BuyerCode", BuyerCode);"? I would guess that the BuyerCode variable is getting nulled out somewhere in your code. Does "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BuyerCode", BuyerCode == null ? "" : BuyerCode);" work?

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "Azure" is giving you an error? Please edit your question to show how you're getting this error (and show the error). Also: Are you using SQL Server in a VM, or the SQL Database service?

Comment: I'm attaching Visual Studio debugger to Azure, sorry.  I'm using Cloud Explorer.  Right clicking the web app, attaching debugger.